# Forcing NN weights to always be in a certain range

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a simple model:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3, 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 30)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(30, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = torch.tanh(self.fc3(x)) 
        return x

    net = Model()
```

How can I keep the weights to **always** be between a certain value (eg -1,1)?

I tried the following:

```
self.fc1 = torch.tanh(nn.Linear(3, 10))
```

Which I'm not entirely sure that will **always** keep them in that value (even if the gradient update is trying to push them farther).

But got the following error:

```
TypeError: tanh(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not Linear
```

Comment: Do you want the weights of the Linear layers to be in range (-1, 1) or the output from the linear layer to be in the range (-1, 1) ? If you want the output to be in that range then use `tanh` otherwise use the `Clipping` technique as specified by @yakhyo.

Comment: I ran the above code snippet you have specified. It ran fine and did not raise the above error specified.

Answer (score 2):

According to the discuss.pytorch you can create extra class to clip weights between a given range. [Link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/set-constraints-on-parameters-or-layers/23620/7) to the discussion.

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3, 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 30)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(30, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = torch.tanh(self.fc3(x)) 
        return x
```

You should add weight clipper:

```py
class WeightClipper(object):
    
    def __call__(self, module):
        # filter the variables to get the ones you want
        if hasattr(module, 'weight'):
            w = module.weight.data
            w = w.clamp(-1,1)
            module.weight.data = w


model = Model()
clipper = WeightClipper()
model.apply(clipper)
```

Comment: Looks great. Just two question, is it possible to apply it to specific layers instead of all the parameters of the model? Say I want to apply it only to `self.fc1`. And also, I was trying to find this in the link you shared but couldn't quite understand. Do I need to call `model.apply` after every pass or will it automatically always clip the weights at every gradient update?

Comment: I still haven't found a way to specify only some layers. From [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/restrict-range-of-variable-during-gradient-descent/1933/3) it seems like I have to call `apply` after every epoch, just wanted to verify with you

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My question is, this way, aren't we interfering with the work of the optimizer?
 I mean, who do we 'tell' the optimizer that we have changed the values he assigned?